# Transparent divider in a listview

Tags: android

I am creating a listiview programmatically. I keep a divider between listview elements.
I wish to keep a transparent divider because I have a background image to be shown. I have tried the following code which does not work. Kindly help

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.news,news));

ListView lv=getListView();

ColorDrawable sage= new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(Color.TRANSPARENT));

lv.setDivider(sage);

lv.setDividerHeight(20);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

**color.xml:** (res > values > color.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="transperent_color">#00000000</drawable>    
</resources>
```

Now,use it like:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.news,news));
ListView lv=getListView();
lv.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transperent_color));
lv.setDividerHeight(20);
```

Comment: Why not put this in drawable instead?

Answer (score 22):

@kusi if you have not setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); then you should have to declare it and then in that layout file you have to declare this ListView

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="20dip"
    />
```

note that you must have to set id of this listview as android:id="@android:id/list" in case you have extends ListActivity in your Activity Class.

Answer (score 10):

this line brings it standardized, usable everywhere ... :)

> **getListView().setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));**

if you also call -> **setDividerHeight**, call setDivider *first*.

good luck && have fun :=)

Comment: Note: call setDivider before setDividerHeight, else its not working

Answer (score 5):

plz use following code for Transparent Divider in List View Its happen for following code

```
lv.setDivider(null);
```

Comment: `ListView` can not calculate right height if divider is null.

Answer (score 4):

In the xml file containing the list view you are using set the attribute android:divider="#00000000" on the list view. You can also set the divider height to 0dp if you wanted.

Comment: setting height 0dp won't just remove the divider or put the default one instead? i bet,he can use 0dp.Instead,he must set it proper height there,not 0dp.Also when you specify divider to something,you must specify divider height to get it affected!

Comment: I'm not sure how the 0dp will affect it but I have used the divider attribute set to the color code for transparent many times and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for SDK >= 15

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add,

```
android:divider="@null"
```

in the xml for the divider. This will ensure that the absence of the divider.