# Android ListView transparent background not working

Tags: android, listview, layout, background, transparent

android:divider transparency is not working. Setting a color (e.g. #BBF232) is working fine. Using "@android:color/transparent" as listview background is working properly aswell. Just when using it as divider nothing happens. 
Any Ideas ?

My XML ListView Code:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp">
```

Comment: Have you tried using "#00FFFFFF" instead of transparent?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162457/transparent-divider-in-a-listview

Comment: yes. It is not working, too

Comment: I looked at this post. I've tried out what they said there. It did not work, that's why I opened this post

Comment: I'm not sure if the white background is the final version, but what about just setting the divider color to the same as your ListView background or removing the divider altogether?

Comment: My layout background is green at the moment. If I'd set android:divider to the same green it would be "transparent" but I am planning to use a picture as background.

Comment: What about setting `android:dividerHeight="0dp"`? You can achieve the same separation with padding in your row xml.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: Are you using a custom row layout? If not, create a new xml and arrange all your items. For the main container, add padding of 5 dp to  the top and bottom (or whole thing). This will give a separation of 10 dp between all cells. Set that as the row layout in your adapter. I'd go into more detail but I actually have to leave and won't be back on until tomorrow. If you still don't have your answer by then, I'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: Nevermind I found the problem :) I removed the background (#FFFFFF) of the ListView and added it to the ListView Layout (listviewcell.xml)
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inside listview use this code:

```
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

If you are using cardview then use the following code:

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```