# create a list of cardview based on items count android

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-cardview

Hello I want to make a list of cardView based on how many strings i have in the InfoGenBibliotheque class. I don't really know how to create a list of cardViews based on items count. If someone could be of help I would appreciate it. I have read that i have to create a cardview layout file to create a list from it. 
//edited
so I managed to make it using a listView and BaseAdapter. But when I execute the application the margins are no where to be found.

InfoGenBibliotheque class:

```
   public class InfoGenBibliotheque {

    private String SalutaionsAnglais [] = {
            "Certainly!",
            "Good afternoon.",
            "Good evening sir.",
            "Good Luck.",
            "Good morning."
    };

    private String SalutaionsFrancais [] = {
            "Certainement!",
            "Bon après-midi.",
            "Bonsoir Monsieur.",
            "Bonne chance.",
            "Bonjour."
    };
}
```

my XML activity_info_generales file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".ui.InfoGeneralesActivity">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

            </ListView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my cardView xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/expressionCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:padding="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expressionFrancais"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Najb Mohammed"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expressionAnglais"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Najb mohammed"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter java file:

```
  public class ExpressionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Expression> expressions;

    public ExpressionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Expression> expressions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expressions = expressions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return expressions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return expressions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.expressions_card_view,null);
        }

        TextView expressionFrancais = convertView.findViewById(R.id.expressionFrancais);
        TextView expressionAnglais = convertView.findViewById(R.id.expressionAnglais);
        Expression expression = expressions.get(position);

        expressionFrancais.setText(expression.getExpressionFrancais());
        expressionAnglais.setText(expression.getExpressionAnglais());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

populating a list of expressions:

```
  public class ListExpression {

    public static ArrayList<Expression> getExpressionList(){
        ArrayList<Expression> expressionList = new ArrayList<>();
        InfoGenBibliotheque infoGenBibliotheque = new InfoGenBibliotheque();
        for(int i = 0;i < infoGenBibliotheque.getSalutaionsAnglais().length;i++){
            expressionList.add(new Expression(i,infoGenBibliotheque.getSalutationFrancais(i),infoGenBibliotheque.getSalutationAnglais(i)));
        }
        return expressionList;
    }
}
```

Expression class

```
    public class Expression {

    private int idExpression;
    private String expressionFrancais;
    private String expressionAnglais;

    public Expression(int idExpression, String expressionFrancais, String expressionAnglais) {
        this.idExpression = idExpression;
        this.expressionFrancais = expressionFrancais;
        this.expressionAnglais = expressionAnglais;
    }

    public int getIdExpression() {

        return idExpression;
    }

    public void setIdExpression(int idExpression) {
        this.idExpression = idExpression;
    }

    public String getExpressionFrancais() {
        return expressionFrancais;
    }

    public void setExpressionFrancais(String expressionFrancais) {
        this.expressionFrancais = expressionFrancais;
    }

    public String getExpressionAnglais() {
        return expressionAnglais;
    }

    public void setExpressionAnglais(String expressionAnglais) {
        this.expressionAnglais = expressionAnglais;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using the `CardView` as root element makes the margins disappear:

[image]

Putting the `CardView` inside a `FrameLayout` gives you the margins:

[image]

(But I personally don't think that the horizontal divider lines look good with the cards. If you want them to be invisible, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162690/5015207) or use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`. )

xml for the second approach:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/expressionCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">
       <!-- skipped inner Views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```